# Filebeat on Azure Kubernetes Service(AKS) with Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, filebeat

I am pretty new to AKS and helm. I need to install filebeat and metricbeat on AKS cluster using Helm Chart. Request any guidance or pointer to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have **kubernetes** cluster up & running and set on **AKS** you can install the **helm** locally or the bastion you are using.

Get and set context of the **kubeconfig** file of **AKS** cluster on local or bastion so you can now access the cluster.

Now, Here is the ready-made **helm chart** of [filebeat](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/elastic/filebeat)

Run the command : `helm repo add elastic https://helm.elastic.co`

it will add the helm repo automatically and after that run command

```
helm install my-filebeat elastic/filebeat --version 8.5.1
```

here we are installing version **8.5.1** you can update other environments and configuration by following the [documentation](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/elastic/filebeat).

Comment: I installed the filebeat using helmchart and configured the config-map in the namespace of my cluster. Next I restarted the pod by deleting it.

$ kubectl get pods
NAME                         READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
my-filebeat-filebeat-vzrl5   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          5s


Now, I am not sure what is to be done.

Comment: push the logs from the appplicatino and set configuration as per requirement how you want to parse the logs and modify it it will be in configmap or so if required other start generating logs and push it or configure to read logs from specific location